# table borders not expanding properly in pdf using itext

Tags: pdf, itext

I would like to generate pdf which contains table with border and having more data in that table so when generating pdf it is generated in two pages. But the problem is table borders not expanding
page to page i.e, in the next page borders(horizontal),previous page vertical border  framed again which is wrong. Horizontal in next page, Vertical in previous page should not come.

Please find the attached pdf file and html file for reference.

[Generated PDf file with my code](http://www.dropbox.com/s/9tvzpx2u6ua1tnc/second_edit.pdf)

[Sample html file](http://www.dropbox.com/s/ewz32wx891tyfjy/sample.html)

Comment: The borders are there by design. If you want to change the way borders are drawn by default, you need to remove the borders (`NO_BORDER`) and implement the `PdfPTable` interface to draw your own custom borders: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTableEvent.html

Comment: Yes,borders are there by design but problem is i have shown in attached pdf file by commenting. Though table creation didn't complete in first page horizontal border and starting in second page horizontal border showing which wrong right. Please once view the attached pdf file to understand the problem.

Comment: I understand your problem. When the table is split, you don't want a bottom border. This means that you have to remove the borders that are there by design and that you need to draw custom borders the way you like it using cell and table events. You may have misunderstood my answer because I wrote `PdfPTable` instead of `PdfPTableEvent`. The link however, referred to the correct class.

Comment: Note that your question is saying that iText's behavior is not correct: *previous page vertical border framed again which is wrong.* That is an opinion, not a fact. The way iText behaves is what most iText users expect. If you want a different behavior, you can fine-tune the way borders are drawn as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want a table that looks like this [custom_border2.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/custom_border2.pdf).

As explained in my comments, you need to set the borders of the cell to `NO_BORDER`, either by changing the default cell:

```
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

Or by changing the properties of specific cells:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(TEXT));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
```

Or both.

Then you have to create a table event:

```
class BorderEvent implements PdfPTableEventAfterSplit {

    protected boolean bottom = true;
    protected boolean top = true;

    public void splitTable(PdfPTable table) {
        bottom = false;
    }

    public void afterSplitTable(PdfPTable table, PdfPRow startRow, int startIdx) {
        top = false;
    }

    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] width, float[] height,
            int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
        float widths[] = width[0];
        float y1 = height[0];
        float y2 = height[height.length - 1];
        float x1 = widths[0];
        float x2 = widths[widths.length - 1];
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        cb.moveTo(x1, y1);
        cb.lineTo(x1, y2);
        cb.moveTo(x2, y1);
        cb.lineTo(x2, y2);
        if (top) {
            cb.moveTo(x1, y1);
            cb.lineTo(x2, y1);
        }
        if (bottom) {
            cb.moveTo(x1, y2);
            cb.lineTo(x2, y2);
        }
        cb.stroke();
        cb.resetRGBColorStroke();
        bottom = true;
        top = true;
    }
}
```

The `splitTable()` and `afterSplitTable()` method will keep track if a top or bottom border needs to be drawn. The actual borders are drawn in the `tableLayout()` method.

You need to set this table event right after creating the table:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
BorderEvent event = new BorderEvent();
table.setTableEvent(event);
```

Now you will have the desired behavior as explained in my initial comment. You can find the full code sample [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/CustomBorder2). I have provided a more complex example [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/CustomBorder).

Comment: This is what i was looking for